# Stack Overflow [wordpress-*] tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, migration, tag-synonyms

I propose we add some of the `[wordpress-*]` tags of Stack Overflow as synonyms on our site, to ease question migrations. Questions tagged `[wordpress] [wordpress-plugin-dev]` lose all their tags as `[wordpress]` is blacklisted and `[wordpress-plugin-dev]` does not exist here - but `[plugin-development]` does.

We should check whether tag synonyms are applied on question migration, but if they are, adding these synonyms could reduce the number of `[untagged]` questions, while having no negative side-effects on our site (since they don't add new tags, they only map to existing ones).

Answer (score 3):

I have created [plugin-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) ← [wordpress-plugin-dev](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin-dev) synonym, let me know if it works and if you need more pairs created.

Comment: It seems to work, [this question was migrated](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/how-do-i-modify-navigation-with-a-plugin) and the tag got renamed. Thanks!